# FormData file upload issue via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, forms, file, upload

I'm trying to perform an image upload via Ajax setting FormData object however when form data is submitted the _FILES variable remains empty and
get HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA=[object Object] not sure what the problem is here but would really appreciate some help on this.

code snippets below:

```html
<form id="test_upload_form" action="/inventory/fileImport">
    <input id="test_file" type="file" name="superfile">
    <input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="<?=$this->nonceField()?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<script>
    $('#test_upload_form').on('submit', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var fileInput = $('#test_file');
        debugger;
        var file = ($('#test_file'))[0].files[0];
        var formData = new FormData($(this));
        formData.append('file', file);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/inventory/fileImport',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            processData: false, // Don't process the files
            contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
                {
                    console.log(data);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Handle errors here
                    console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                // Handle errors here
                console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
                // STOP LOADING SPINNER
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Just amended the Javascript to the below and it seems to be working now.
Just doesn't work with Jquery.

```html
$('#test_upload_form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var file = ($('#test_file'))[0].files[0];
        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("test_upload_form"));
        formData.append('file', file);
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", "/inventory/fileImport");
        formData.append("serialnumber", 'asdasdsadas');
        request.send(formData);
});
```

Comment: Try to set `dataType: 'text'` as you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23981045/1959181)

Comment: Nope still not working

Answer (score 1):

FormData is waiting for a standard javascript DOM object and you are using a jQuery object

Try using

```
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("test_upload_form"));
```

instead of `$(this)` or you can also convert your jQuery object using `$(this)[0]`